# Delphi TWebBrowser.GoBack: How to handle redirects

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I am having a problem with the `TWebBrowser` with regards to the `GoBack` method. Below is the navigation history which shows the problem:

```
[1] htt#://www.google.com/
[2] htt#://news.google.com/nwshp?hl=en&tab=wn
[3] htt#://news.google.com/news/url?sr=1&ct2=us%2F0_0_s_3_1_a&sa=t&usg=AFQjCNGgo-FdxdVP4AVI_HZEV7gS66cjDA&cid=43982236066804&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnews.cnet.com%2F8301-10805_3-57613303-75%2Fmicrosoft-provides-doctors-note-for-sick-xbox-one-gamers%2F&ei=ORaOUvjjJciMgQeGwAE&rt=HOMEPAGE&vm=STANDARD&bvm=section&did=2559730436932654466&ssid=tc
[4] htt#://news.cnet.com/8301-10805_3-57613303-75/microsoft-provides-doctors-note-for-sick-xbox-one-gamers/
```

After arriving at #4, I execute the `GoBack` procedure.  This is when the problem occurs. `GoBack` removes [4] from the history list and goes to [3] which unfortunately reloads [4] which effectively cancels the `GoBack` request.

What I would like is to allow [3] to initiate [4] but prevent itself from remaining on the stack so that the stack would look like this:

```
[1] htt#://www.google.com/
[2] htt#://news.google.com/nwshp?hl=en&tab=wn
[3] htt#://news.cnet.com/8301-10805_3-57613303-75/microsoft-provides-doctors-note-for-sick-xbox-one-gamers/
```

How might I do this?

Comment: To twebbrowser.onbeforenavigate2 you can set  Cancel:=false; **- abort curent navigation** .` if (pos('news.google.com/news/url',url)>0) then 
begin 
**Cancel:=false;** goback +1 url ` end . Please vote up if helph my answer? I will be heppy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the twebbrowser.onbeforenavigate2 event. it is called before the browser loads a new resource. you can use it to cancel or redirect the request.

Answer (score 0):

Put some code to `twebbrowser.onbeforenavigate2` event or `state change` or other see it all what each mening

```
 if (pos('news.google.com/news/url',url)>0) then 
begin 
Cancel:=false; //see it abort curent navigation
//go back +1 pages
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `TWebbrowser.OnBeforeNavigate2` does not work for server-side redirects!